# Titanium PushNotification How to display in one group?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I am facing a problem with development a application.
I am using a Cloud Push Notification with Titanium Appcelerator. 
I have need display push Notification in Group. 
How display this is display in single particular particular tab?
I am sharing 2 images

Currently looking like this.

[image: Currently looking like this.]

I have need look like this. How do?
[image: I have need look like this. How do?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a Big View Notification Style but it is only available in 4.1 or newer

quote from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#BigNotify):

> A notification's big view appears only when the notification is expanded, which happens when the notification is at the top of the notification drawer, or when the user expands the notification with a gesture. Expanded notifications are available starting with Android 4.1.

in the same [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ApplyStyle), you can find a sample how to use this. there are also som tips/hints how to maintain [compatibility](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Compatibility) with older devices (not only regarded to the big view)

Comment: Thanks for you revert. but How i can use with Titanium Appcelerator.
CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function(evt) {  
 Ti.API.info("cloudpush " + evt.payload);

});

Comment: oh i overread the Appcelerator part inyour question. There i cant help, sorry. i never used Appcelerator.

Answer (score 0):

you must put the following code in your TiApp.xml

```
<property name="acs-grouped-notification-message-" type="string">You have $number$ unread messages.</property>
```

Comment: Try to flesh out your answer a bit more.